# How to disable user pointer sanitization

Tags: linux, cpu, performance, 64-bit, spectre

I’ve got a python (so single threaded) intensive process performing a lot of context switches that need to run during days.

Despite using `nopti noibrs noibp nospec_store_bypass_disable spectre_store_bypass_disable=off pti=off nospectre_v2 spectre_v2=off spectre_v2_user=off spectre_v1=off no_stf_barrier mds=off tsx=on l1tf=off kvm-intel.vmentry_l1d_flush=never tsx_async_abort=off kvm.nx_huge_pages=off` on the kernel cmdline, `/sys/devices/system/cpu/vulnerabilities/spectre_v1` still shows `__user pointer sanitization` is enabled.

How to disable it ?

Comment: Do you have data showing that pointer sanitization has a measurable impact on context switches?

Comment: @squircle no the exact numbers I recognize. What’s sure is I can’t compare since I can’t have a reference with it being disabled. Just that it adds more works inside context switches.

Comment: Can you share your source on that last bit?